# SPI set up on stm32

Tags: stm32, spi

i use to set up Display with SPI communication, and i use GPIO Pins CLK, MOSI, RES, DC, CS,

my question is how to set up GPIO_Output pins RES, DC, CS
[GPIO Set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh10v.jpg)

i need to leave default or need to set up pool up?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

For push-pull type output, you don't need the internal pull-up/pull-down.

If you use open-drain output and your board does not have the necessary resistors, you can use the internal pull-up or pull-down, depending on what is required.